# How to make Internet facing website in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a local sharepoint website running.I want to make it some thing like abcdefg.com.How can I achieve this in sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to enable anonymous access on your WebSite, follow this link for detailed steps.

[Enable Anonymous Access in SharePoint 2010](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010)

Here's another article on how to create a web application in SharePoint with your own domain name

[Creating your first SharePoint 2010 site](http://en.hugon.ws/articles/sharepoint-2010/creating-your-first-sharepoint-2010-site/)

> Also get the hosting company to setup the DNS records first.  They
>   should all point to the IP address of the SharePoint server. Then
>   create the site collections specifying the names you want to use in
>   the New-SPSite command.   Once the HTTP request reaches the SharePoint
>   server it will handle routing the request to the right Host named Site
>   Collection.

[Reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d81e8d98-8229-493d-a909-4a526fa2678a/host-header-site-collections-with-their-own-domain-names)